# Inductor Value Reading

Tags: inductor

[image]I see these values written on inductor symbols on the schematic of an RF filter/PA, what to make of these values?

a) what does "4T1.5D*0.31" means?

b) what does "CM" means in this expression "1uH/CM"?

c) what does "CI" means in this expression "1uH/CI"?

Comment: Impossible to say without more context. They look more like formulas or proportions than values.

Comment: Would you believe the second is 1 \$\mu\$Henry per centimeter?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is instructions for constructing a coil: 4 turns, 1.5 inches(?) diameter, 0.31 long.

CM may mean comon-mode, but I don't know what CI would be.